# Convert HEX to RGB in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, hex, excel-2010, radix

I have a column "HEX" and three columns "R", "G", and "B".

How can I convert a HEX to RGB, e.g. `ff0000` to `R=255`, `G=0`, and `B=0`?

I know that the first 2 characters `ff` belongs to "R", the next 2 `00` belongs to "G", and the final 2 `00` belongs to "B". So I will have to use `=LEFT(A1, 2)` for "R", `=RIGHT(LEFT(A1, 4), 2)`, and `=RIGHT(A1, 2)` for the last.

But how can I convert `ff` to `255` and `00` to `0`, etc.? I guess I will have to do something to parse from hexadecimal (base 16) to decimal (base 10)?

I would like to do it without VBA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert from hex to decimal using the `HEX2DEC()` function. For instance:

```
=HEX2DEC(A1)
```

Where cell `A1` contains the string `FF`, this will return `255`.

[More details here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/HEX2DEC-function-8c8c3155-9f37-45a5-a3ee-ee5379ef106e).

Answer (score 18):

You can try with the `=Hex2Dec(A1)` indeed, but you should split its input into 3 parts:

One for **R**, one for **G** and one for **B**, considering that you would always get them in a format like this **ff0000**.

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(B1,2))&"-"&HEX2DEC(MID(B1,3,2))&"-"&HEX2DEC(RIGHT(B1,2))
```

This is the result from the formula:

[image]

Comment: The OP has already stated that they will be splitting the hex string into its component parts.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to create a excel spreadsheet that converts Hex to RGB in three columns; Red, Green and Blue.  Below is the code for it:
Red: `=HEX2DEC(LEFT([Cell],2))`
Green: `=HEX2DEC(MID([Cell],3,2))`
Blue: `=HEX2DEC(RIGHT([Cell],2))`
So far, I have not found any restrictions to this code.
I also made code for RGB to hex:
`=DEC2HEX(([Red]*65536)+([Green]*256)+[Blue],6)`
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

Some pages make that ([w3SCHOOL PICKER](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp)), but in excel you can make this

[vba rgb to hex and inverse](https://code.adonline.id.au/rgb-to-hex-in-excel/)

If you try without vba, you'll only can use 56 colors.
(in case use the colors from a cell)

Comment: The OP isn't looking to display the colours in Excel, so this doesn't seem relevant. The OP's question was how to convert hex colour values into RGB colour values within Excel, which can be accomplished using the HEX2DEC() function (without any restriction on the number of possible colours past that of hex colour codes).