# How do I copy only the red text in a cell to another cell?

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have cells that contain different colour text in Excel. I want to be able to extract the text that is in a particular colour to another cell.

How can I amend my UDF to account for this?

```
Function RedText(Rng As Range) As String
  Dim X As Long, S As String
  S = Rng.Text
  For X = 1 To Len(Rng.Text)
    If Rng.Characters(X, 1).Font.Color <> vbRed Then
      If Mid(S, X, 1) <> vbLf Then Mid(S, X, 1) = " "
    End If
  Next
  RedText = Replace(Replace(Application.Trim(S), " " & vbLf, vbLf), vbLf & " ", vbLf)
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having with that code?  If I test that function then it does only return the part of the text in red

Comment: I want the function to be able to accept a HEX code as argument, because I have text in many different colours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833797/convert-hex-to-rgb-in-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```vb
Function TextByColor(Rng As Range, hex As String) As String
  Dim X As Long, S As String, clr As Long
  S = Rng.Text
  clr = HexToRGB(hex)
  For X = 1 To Len(Rng.Text)
    If Rng.Characters(X, 1).Font.Color <> clr Then
      If Mid(S, X, 1) <> vbLf Then Mid(S, X, 1) = " "
    End If
  Next
  RedText = Replace(Replace(Application.Trim(S), " " & vbLf, vbLf), vbLf & " ", vbLf)
End Function

Function HexToRGB(hex As String) As Long
    Dim r, g, b
    r = Application.Hex2Dec(Left(hex, 2))
    g = Application.Hex2Dec(Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    b = Application.Hex2Dec(Right(hex, 2))
    HexToRGB = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function

'Added: >10x faster alternative to using `Application.Hex2Dec`
Function HexToRGB2(hex As String) As Long
    Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
    b = CLng("&H" & Right(hex, 2))
    g = CLng("&H" & Mid(hex, 3, 2))
    r = CLng("&H" & Left(hex, 2))
    HexToRGB2 = RGB(r, g, b)
End Function
```

Usage: `=textbycolor(A3,"0000FF")`

As noted in the comments - here's why you can't use HEX2DEC on the full hex value (R and G components get switched):

[image]

Comment: @TimWilliams *(Neglecting the evident typos in function returns,)* I suppose that the HexToRGB function assignments should be in the order of `r` (getting the right side `FF`), `g` (`00`), b (`00`) as afaik the RGB() function actually creates a BGR value :-)

Comment: @T.M. -  `HexToRGB("FF0000")` (after fixing the typo) return 255 which is correct I think?  See screenshot above comparing HEX2DEC() and HexToRGB()